# MongoDB indexed queries returning incorrect values since upgrading to 2.6 from 2.4

Tags: mongodb

Since upgrading from 2.4 to 2.6 I've found indexes are causing some queries to produce incorrect values.

Our dataset is like this:

```js
// This is a simplified harness to replicate what we're seeing in our DB
/** number_user_id indexes **/
db.getCollection("number_user_id").ensureIndex({
  "_id": NumberInt(1)
},[]);

/** number_user_id indexes **/
db.getCollection("number_user_id").ensureIndex({
  "user_id": NumberLong(1)
},[]);

/** number_user_id indexes **/
db.getCollection("number_user_id").ensureIndex({
  "number": NumberLong(1)
},[]);

/** number_user_id indexes **/
db.getCollection("number_user_id").ensureIndex({
  "user_id": NumberLong(1),
  "number": NumberLong(1)
},{
  "unique": true
});

/** number_user_id records **/
db.getCollection("number_user_id").insert({
  "_id": ObjectId("537dc86a80f1cf0e42d63af1"),
  "number": null,
  "user_id": 1
});
db.getCollection("number_user_id").insert({
  "_id": ObjectId("537dc87f80f1cf0f42d63af1"),
  "number": 2,
  "user_id": 1
});
db.getCollection("number_user_id").insert({
  "_id": ObjectId("537dc87580f1cf0d42d63af1"),
  "number": 1,
  "user_id": 1
});
```

The query differences are as follows:

```js
db.number_user_id.find({ $or: [{ number: null }, { number: { $lte: 2 } }] });
// On 2.4 you get all 3 documents back on 2.6 you get 1 document back

db.number_user_id.find({ $or: [{ number: null }, { number: { $lte: 2 } }] }).count();
// On 2.4 you get 3 on 2.6 you get 1
```

If I remove the joint index I can get correct results but that comprimises data integrity.

I can't find this scenario in the docs/changelog. So I'm wondering whether I need to do different indexes, rewrite queries or if I've found a MongoDB bug.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me.

Comment: This is defn odd behaviour. I noticed if you create a sparse index on the "number" index, then the query works as expected.

Comment: Thanks, it's been confirmed as a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a confirmed bug https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14030

due to be fixed in MongoDB 2.6.2 https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13960